# React Native run android error Could not find method google()

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile, native

i use Android studio 2.3.3
npm -v 6.12.0
react-native --version 3.0.4

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "25.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 15
        compileSdkVersion = 25
        targetSdkVersion = 25
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

run react-native and get error in line 11 **google()** in install app on simulator

Comment: i change `maven url ` value to  **url 'https://maven.google.com'** but not install